# Displaying ampersand in form label - C#

Tags: c#

If I build a simple string like this:

```
string myStr = "Kayla & William";
```

And then simply set the label text on a form like this:

```
lbl_Phrase.Text = myStr;
```

The output in the form removes the ampersand (&)

[image]

---

I've tried:

- escaping the &
- ASCII encoding
- char.ConvertFromUtf32(38)

---

When I debug and step through the code the string includes the `&` just fine.  Also, I can write the string to `Debug.WriteLine(myStr);` and it looks great.

Is the problem related to how the form displays the string?  How can I get the label to display the `&`?

Comment: @Szymon thanks, I missed that one due to my last minute change I made in searching.

Comment: I can't delete without the answer being removed

Comment: Don't worry, it will be put on hold soon. You don't need to remove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to escape it with use double ampersand `&&`  for displaying single ampersand `&`

Note : single `&` has different meaning that it will be treated as `ACCESS KEY PREFIX` character and you need to escape it with another &

Try This :

```
&&
```

OR

you can set `UseMnemonic` property of the `label` to `false`, and give only `one` ampersand  `&` .when you set `UseMnemonic` to `false` ampersand will be treated as normal literal and displayed.

Comment: so why does this happen?

Comment: This solves the problem in the form but it alters the actual string in code.  Is there away around this?

Comment: single `&` has different meaning you need to escape it with another

Comment: set `UseMnemonic` to false for label, and try giving only one ampersand.